# OpenQA.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: 'Element should have been "select" but was input'

Tags: selenium-webdriver

For dropdown list I use the below code

```
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("select2-search__field")));
select.SelectByIndex(0);
select.SelectByText("Checking0");
```

But this error occured

```
OpenQA.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: 'Element should have been "select" but was input'
```

Comment: Please paste your HTML code here. Probably your dropdown doesn't contains `select` tag.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Read the above link to know what is select tag in HTML ,

The select could only be used for 'select' tag. As in your question your class is   'select2-search__field' its not a select tag and more over looks like a search field to search for drop down content.